# What to use the "fd_set *writefds" parameter in the select() statement for

Tags: c

This is the prototype of the select statement (acc to man pages):

```
    int select(int n, fd_set *readfds, fd_set *writefds, fd_set *exceptfds,
           struct timeval *timeout);
```

I know what to use the readfds parameter for: with this one you can see if data was written to one of your sockets. On the other hand, the writefds page that I found, states that this is to see "if any of the sockets is ready to send() data to". But what does this mean? In Windows Sockets Network Programming by Quin and Shute it says that this detects either the connected or the writable state. What is the point of this? Is it simply to check whether a socket still has a connection to a connected client and test whether is has any use writing something to that socket?

So: what does one normally use writefds for?

Comment: select is really an obsolete interface. I'd recommend using a library such as libevent if possible (it's BSD licenced)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you keep writing to a `TCP` socket and the other side doesn't receive as fast as you send, there comes a time when **`write` blocks**. You want to avoid that so you need to test that "you can write without blocking". Because this normally doesn't happen in test programs, it could come as a shock, but **`write(2)` and `send(2)` can block**.

So if `select(2)` says a `fd` is set in `writefds` then it means any `write` or `send` on it will actually write at least one byte without blocking.

#### EDIT

From [the standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html):

> The pselect() function shall examine the file descriptor sets whose
> addresses are passed in the readfds, **writefds**, and errorfds parameters
> to see whether some of their descriptors are ready for reading, are
> **ready for writing**, or have an exceptional condition pending,
> respectively.

Comment: Ok thnx, this was the answer I was looking for. By the way, why do your write select(2) instead of select(), what does it mean?

Comment: @Django It's the [manual section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page#Manual_sections). `2` is for system calls.

Comment: Ok, I see. I have been searching these pages to find out what writefds exactly means a.o. where select(2) is described but I could not find it. Is it somewhere in these pages?

Comment: Yeah ok, I saw that, but where did you get that juicy detail that a writable state means that it will send at least one byte?

Comment: @Django Well if it's writable, it has to send **something**. In practice I have only seen `write` act like this a few times (when forced by  a nasty kernel module).

Comment: Do you agree with what Per says (see above) that select() is an obsolete interface, suggesting that up-to-date programmers do not use it anymore?

Comment: @Django You should use `epoll` / `kqueue` / `sigio` instead of `select`.

Comment: Are these functions in the standard c library or is this an additional library?

Comment: @Django They aren't functions, they are different mechanisms. You need to use a search engine to find out which is best for you.