# What does `POLLOUT` event in `poll` Linux function mean?

Tags: c++, c, linux

From Linux documentation, `POLLOUT` means *Normal data may be written without blocking*. Well, but this explanation is ambigous.
How much data is it possible to write without blocking after `poll` reported this event? 1 byte? 2 bytes? Gigabyte?
After `POLLOUT` event on blocking socket, how to check how much data I can send to socket without block?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use POLLOUT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12170037/when-to-use-pollout)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

poll system call only tells you that there is something happen in the file descriptor(physical device) but it doesn't tell you how much space is available for you to read or write. In order to know exactly how many bytes data is available to be used for reading or writing, you must use read() or write() system call to get the return value which says the number of bytes you have actually been read or written.

Thus,poll() is mainly used for applications that must use multiple input or output streams without getting stuck on any one of them. You can't use write() or read() in this case since you can't monitor multiple descriptors at the same time within one thread.

BTW,for device driver,the underlying implementation for POLL in driver usually likes this(code from ldd3):

```
  static unsigned int scull_p_poll(struct file *filp, poll_table *wait)
    {

      poll_wait(filp, &dev->inq, wait);
      poll_wait(filp, &dev->outq, wait);
      ...........
      if (spacefree(dev))
          mask |= POLLOUT | POLLWRNORM; /* writable */
      up(&dev->sem);
      return mask; 
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

If `poll()` sets the `POLLOUT` flag then at least one byte may be written without blocking.  You may then find that a `write()` operation performs only a partial write, so indicated by returning a short count.  You must always be prepared for partial reads and writes when multiplexing I/O via `poll()` and/or `select()`.